# jQuery Enter keyup function needs to be hit twice before function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup, function-call

I have an event listener that looks for the keyup of the enter key in an input box. There is also a button that is next to the submission box that the user can click which submits the data and triggers a function. On the keyup, I am directly calling the function.

The issue is that the function only works when I press enter the second time. Example: I enter a number and hit enter, the page goes into a loading modal like it should, but nothing gets displayed on the page. If I click on the input box again (not changing the number I inputted) and hit enter again, it goes into the loading modal and then it displays the charts that I have.

I am unsure on why it works the second time but not the first? I have seen multiple posts on pressing once triggering multiple function calls, but can't find anything that you need to do an event twice just to get one function call.

Here is the jQuery for enter key

```
document.getElementById('SN').addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    self.getInformation();
                }
            });
```

Here is the input box.

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label class="control-label" for="SN">Serial Number</label>
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="SN" name="SN" type="number" data-bind="value: SN" />
                </div>
```

Here is the button that works when the user actually clicks it instead of hitting enter in the input box.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-3">
                    <label></label>
                    <button id="getInformationBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-bind="click: getInformation">Get Information</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your description sounds like the problem is elsewhere. Please create a [mre]. (posted code is fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/46zf2qr1/)

Comment: Whatd does self refer to? post your whole html document so we can help, or refer to a live page, and where is jQuery code, it's vanilla JavaScript

Comment: Are you using Knockout.JS?

Comment: Knockout is used for the button at the data-bind. And the data-bind calls the function. For the Enter Keyup, i have done $('#getInformationBtn).click(); as well as just calling the getInformation() function directly and both result in this issue.

Comment: You want just to bind enter to click the Get Informations button?

Comment: From what I have seen, you can't bind enter to an input. But in regards to binding it to the getInformationBtn, since it is a button, you aren't really selecting it in order to hit enter, hence the click is what submits the function.

Comment: No I didn't mean really bind it by the meaning of the word I meant you want to have the same behaviour of pressing that button when actually pressing Enter

Comment: Seriously redacting many lines is basically what you're supposed to do for a [mre]. I linked to a working example, so the code in your question works fine, which means it's useless. Also, just for reference, if you put the input in a form, then intercept the form's submission event, you no longer need to manually catch the user pressing enter (example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/vhs1rLfe/)

Comment: Ah yes. I thought that is what I did as the data-bind click on the button just calls the function getInformation and the input calls the function getInformation as well.

Comment: As I was writing my last comment I just had an idea. Is it possible that when I manually click the submit button, it is technically clicking off of the input box which then stores the input and getInformation only works with a serial Number, hence when I hit enter in the input box the first time, there is no serial number stored as you never left the input box and it works the second time because the input box was clicked off of and then clicked on again?

Comment: Just tested it. So here is what is happening... I input the serial number and press enter and it doesn't work. BUT (on a new page load) if I enter the serial number, click off of the input box, and the click onto the input box again, and then hit enter. It works. Any suggestions?